# Understanding the boot process and dual booting

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a new computer that I want to run both Windows and Ubuntu.

When I install ubuntu or windows using an USB drive, is it the bios that will display which operating system I want to boot into during system restarts?

Will be installing both operating systems automatically give me this 'choose which operating system' to boot into?

Is resizing hard drives AFTER I have installed both operating systems be possible without any special software?

Answer (score 0):

BIOS knows and displays only a choice of potential boot devices, and the order in which it will try each.

Dual boot is often on a single device, and is controlled by a boot manager, such as Grub (Ubuntu installs Grub along with itself).

For example, the system on which I am writing this has one bootable hard drive.  On that drive are separate partitions for Windows and Ubuntu.  BIOS sees only that the drive is bootable.  When BIOS initiates boot from the hard drive, Grub is what is started.  Grub's menu gives me the choice to start either Windows or Ubuntu.

A fundamental issue here is that "boot" actually occurs at several levels: BIOS knows only hardware.  On each bootable hardware device, there is an entity such as Grub or the Windows boot manager, or something else which "boots" some sort of operating system.  The operating system startup which follows is also often called "booting".

Back in the day, one entered a "bootstrap" program manually, in binary, from a control panel.  That was enough code to start the media reader (punched paper tape or magnetic tape) to read and load the operating system.  Since then the meaning of "boot" has been overbroadly applied to components of a much more complex startup process.

Comment: so b/c you installed ubuntu first, grub takes control?  If I install windows 1st, it will be some other boot manager?

Comment: If you install Ubuntu, or any of several other flavors of Linux, Grub becomes the default boot manager and will generally offer a menu with each of the installed operating systems on it, including Windows.  Windows has its own boot manager which does not play nice with non-Windows operating systems.  If an Ubuntu install sees Windows already present, it will offer you the choice to coexist (dual-boot via Grub) or replace Windows altogether.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu/Grub first, then install Windows, I am pretty sure Windows will ignore Ubuntu and replace Grub with its own Windows-only loader.